# Returning php call as href value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, href

I'm quite new to using php so im not sure if this is possible or not;

What I'm looking to do is call a php function from within a href tag, and use the returned value as the tag..

for example, i have the following code:

## HTML

```
<a href= 'tele.php'> <img src="images/image1" alt="Preview1" /> </a>
```

then:

## PHP

```
<?php
return header("Location: tel:762347723447");    
exit;       
?>
```

I want the href tag to be what the php code returns: "Location: tel:762347723447".
Is it possible to do this? or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: i think what you are looking for is ajax.

Comment: Create a javascript function and call it on the click of your anchor tag and from this javascript function send the user to your php file.

Comment: <?php return header("Location: tel:762347723447"); setting location in the header function requires a valid url, not a telephone number. Also you can't set a header after output (without buffering).

Comment: @NicholasKing I doubt he needs AJAX, just php that writes <a href="tel:762347723447">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header()` returns void, so that PHP code doesn't return anything.

But you probably want something like this:

```
<?php
   function foo() {
       return "tel:762347723447"
   }
?>

<a href= '<?php echo foo(); ?>'> <img src="images/image1" alt="Preview1" /> </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way. I'm unsure of what you're trying to do, but if you want your HTML to call tele.php, get the output of some PHP and replace the HREF, look into AJAX

### HTML

```
<a id="this-link-id" href="tele.php"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Previe1" /></a>

<script> 
    $.post( $('#this-link-id').attr('href'), {}, function( response ) {
        $('#this-link-id').attr('href', response);
    });
</script>
```

### PHP (tele.php)

```
<?php
echo 'tel:762347723447';
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use jQuery and ajax to it then you can have effect which you want.

more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/